# <hr> not showing inside <option>

Tags: html, css

I have this selection element in my vue project

```
<div class="resultContainer">
   <section>
      <option class="resultBtn" v-for="exchange in finalExchanges"> {{exchange}} <hr></option>
    </section>
  </div>
```

The `v-for="exchange in finalExchanges"` is from vue and is irrelevant to my problem
My css code is

```
hr {
 border: 0;
 height: 1px;
 width: 75%;
 background: #e8edf4;
}

.resultContainer {
   margin: auto;
   width: 60%;
   height: 80vh;
   overflow: scroll;
 }

.resultBtn {
   background-color: #59c3c3;
   border: none;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

The problem is that the `<hr>` tag doesn't appear, i noticed that if I use `<ul>` and `<li>` the `<hr>` shows,how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hr` is not a valid child of `option`

[4.10.10. The option element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-option-element)

> **Content model:**
>
> - If the element has a `label` attribute and a `value` attribute: **Nothing**.
> - If the element has a `label` attribute but no `value` attribute: **Text**.
> - If the element has no `label` attribute: and is not a child of a `datalist` element: **Text that is not inter-element white space.**
> - If the element has no `label` attribute and is a child of a `datalist` element: **Text**.

So the content can only be `Text` or `Nothing`

If you want to group elements you can use `optgroup` or and if you want to have a separator you could use this - hackish - solution:

```
<option disabled>──────────</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<option>` tag is child of `<select>` tag. And in browser `<select>` has it's own style.

In short you can't use `<hr>` in `<option>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to add a horizontal line between your options then you can make use of divider class from bootstrap like this

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  <li class='divider'></li>
  <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```